# Stop TabChange in primefaces <p:tabView>`

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tabview

I am using Primefaces 5 and use  which has severl tabs.

In each tab I have a dataTable which either can be in editable or not depending to user action.

I want to stay in the same tab and prevent tab change if user is editing a row, otherwise go to the clicked tab. How should i do it ??

This is my xhtml :

```
<p:tabView  id="customerTab"
            orientation="left"
            dynamic="false"
            cache="false" 
            widgetVar="detailsTab" 
            activeIndex="#{myBean.activTab}"
            >

     <p:ajax  event="tabChange" listener="#{myBean.onTabChange}" update="customerTabv" />


        <p:tab  tab1> </p:tab>
        <p:tab  tab2> </p:tab>
```

This is my backing bean:

```
public void onTabChange(
        TabChangeEvent event) {
    if (Tab.isInEditMode()) {

        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Tab Changed", "Active Tab: " + event.getTab().getId()
                + "You can not change the tab when you are in Edit mode!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

        this.messagesTab.setActiveIndex(0);
        //          //          RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("tabWidget.select(0)");
        activTab = 0;

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().setProcessingEvents(false);


    } else {
                TabView tabView = (TabView) event.getComponent();
                int activeIndex = tabView.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab());
                this.messagesTab.setActiveIndex(activeIndex);
                activTab = activeIndex;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution in short boils down to this:

1. In the onstart of the rowEditInit ajax event, set a client-side variable that you are in edit mode
2. In the oncomplete of the rowEditCancel event, set the client-side variable that your are in a non-edit mode
3. In the oncomplete of the rowEdit event, set the client-side variable that your are in a non-edit mode
4. In the onstart of the tab change event, write some javascript that checks for the value of this edit variable and if in edit mode, return false. The tabChange should **not** happen then. If in non-edit mode, return true and the tabChange happens

Sorry, I do not write an answer for you with a fully working example. This is mainly because I do not want to/have the time to write it (never used inline editing myself for complexity reasons like this) AND think that people 'learn' more from hints then fully worked out code.

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with tabView and nested dynamic elements like dataTable in it. So I use the tabView now only as trigger. This means the tabView has tabs but inside the tabs are not elements. I react with ajax listener to tab changes and update a specific area in my UI which shows the content that should be inside the tab.
For your problem this could be a solution. You can ignore the tab change event when the dataTable is edited.
Or disable the other tabs with tab disabled attribute.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was some javascript. In order to stop tabchange:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" activeIndex="#{controller.tabSelected}"  onTabChange="handleTabChange(index);return false;"
```

Check primefaces_user_guide_6_2 for the handleTabChange function.

I also needed p:remoteCommand to send the new selected tab to the bean.